# How to get file created data using Unix FTP?

Tags: windows, unix, ftp, sftp, last-modified

I'm trying to FTP a file from window to Unix server. Can you please suggest the command(s), so that I can get the file's last modified date ,to check the age of file and continue the next logical flow in the Unix script??

Comment: Do you want to use a BATCH script on Windows to get the date of file on your Windows box? Or a BATCH script on Windows that talks to an FTP server to get a file's date? Or a `bash` script on Unix to get a local file's date? Or a `bash` script on Unix to talk to a Windows FTP server and get the date of file on a a Windows filesystem?

Comment: I'm try for bash script on Unix to get local file's date..

Comment: Check out the manpage for the `stat` command. Then use `filedate=$(stat ??? yourFile)`

Comment: I tried with stats %y Filaname . From the logs, using the script I'm able to connect to the destination server but no proxy connection.